# Apache Mahout itemsimilarity java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /temp/prepareRatingMatrix/numUsers.bin

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, mahout

I have Mahout installed on Spark + Hadoop.

Versions:
spark 1.6.1
scala 2.10.5
java 1.7
mahout 0.12.2

When running `./mahout itemsimilarity --input hdfs://server:port/path/to/input/ --output /home/user/hdfs_tmp/mahout-output`

I get the following error.  BTW, I was able to run the example to classify the newsarticles successfully.

Here's the stack trace:

```
    17/03/13 21:02:26 INFO Job: Job job_1489088506976_0021 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1489088506976_0021_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

17/03/13 21:02:26 INFO Job: Counters: 17
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=21
        Killed map tasks=4909
        Killed reduce tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=27
        Other local map tasks=16
        Data-local map tasks=12
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=973328
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=243332
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=0
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=243332
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=996687872
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/user/temp/prepareRatingMatrix/numUsers.bin
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2045)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSInputStream.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:767)
    at org.apache.mahout.common.HadoopUtil.readInt(HadoopUtil.java:335)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.similarity.item.ItemSimilarityJob.run(ItemSimilarityJob.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.similarity.item.ItemSimilarityJob.main(ItemSimilarityJob.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.FileNotFoundException): File does not exist: /user/user/temp/prepareRatingMatrix/numUsers.bin
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2045)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1226)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: And does `/user/user/temp/prepareRatingMatrix/numUsers.bin` exist?

Comment: no. hence the error. :)  no idea what that file is. Something mahout creates? hadoop?

Comment: That path looks very suspicious with `/user/user` and this hadoop mapreduce code is being deprecated, try the newer `spark-itemsimilarity` it is much more flexible--but I think you may know that :-)

Comment: My data isn't in the right format, so I need to get there first before trying to run again.  Good to know spark-itemsimilarity is different from itemsimilarity!